# Overriding Create PDF button on Quote object to choose the default template?

Tags: pdf, quote, quote-template

In our salesforce org, when we click on the standard "create PDF" button on the quote object, it shows dialog box asking to "choose template" and our sales people always select the same template.

Sales people now want to know if there is a way to avoid this step so that when they click on the create PDF button the default template should be automatically selected and take them directly to PDF preview page.

How do I achieve this? Any suggestions please on where to start on this?

Comment: Since this is a Standard Button, you need to create a VF page according to your requirement and override this button using this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the code for the create PDF button in the below image [image] and created a new custom button with that code and now it works fine and I successfully skipped the step of choosing the template.

Below is the new custom button with code from the above step:

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you please post the code of the button? thnks.